# How to terminate a process by name AND location using C WinAPI?

Tags: windows, winapi

I searched and found a way to terminate a process only by name:

```
void KillProcessByName(TCHAR *szPName) 
{ 
    HANDLE hSnapShot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPALL, NULL); 
    PROCESSENTRY32 pEntry; 
    pEntry.dwSize = sizeof (pEntry); 
    BOOL hRes = Process32First(hSnapShot, &pEntry); 
    while(hRes) 
    { 
        if(!_tcsicmp(pEntry.szExeFile, szPName)) 
        { 
            HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE, 0, 
                                          (DWORD) pEntry.th32ProcessID); 
            if (hProcess != NULL) 
            { 
                TerminateProcess(hProcess, 9); 
                CloseHandle(hProcess); 
            } 
        } 
        hRes = Process32Next(hSnapShot, &pEntry); 
    } 
    CloseHandle(hSnapShot); 
}
```

However, I can't find a member called szLocation or sth alike in the PROCESSENTRY32 structure. I need to distinguish two processes with the same name, but different locations.

Comment: PS: Location here means the path of the process exe. It can be viewed in the Windows Task Manager.

Comment: Have you tried reading the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684839%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply read `szExeFile` from [`PROCESSENTRY32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684839.aspx).

Or you can use [`GetModuleFileNameEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms683198.aspx) to return the full path to the executable file associated with a process handle.

Comment: I see. Thx! GetModuleFileNameEx will help.